# Error processing archive while installing Mate on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, mate

I got this error when trying to install Mate 1.8.1 on ubuntu 14.04:

```
Unpacking mate-applets (1.8.1+dfsg1-1~trusty1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mate-applets_1.8.1+dfsg1-1~trusty1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/cpufreq-selector.1.gz', which is also in package gnome-applets 3.5.92-0ubuntu3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mate-applets_1.8.1+dfsg1-1~trusty1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And actually this is the output after running the command apt-get -f install, nothing changes. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

After asking at the IRC channel of ubuntu-eg, I received an answer that worked for me:

```
dpkg -P gnome-applets
apt-get -f install
```